# How To add WebView in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, listview, webview, android-webview, expandablelistview

**how can i add webview in expandable list view?**
i need to add html file (which can be done using webview) under expandableListView

**Any tutorial**? How can i do it?

is there any other method of doing the same?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="91dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 android:background="#ffffff">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="91dp"
android:id="@+id/sth_cell_img_correct"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/icon_checked" />    <WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:id="@+id/sth_web_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Want to have a `single WebView` as a child of expandable list view?

Comment: @makata Yes Exactly!

Comment: If you are familiar with basic BaseExpandableListAdapter and WebView, this should not be difficult. Have you understood basic ExpandableList, so that I may give you a snippet?

Comment: @makata Yup sure.... will be so grateful :)

Comment: A WebView is a scrollable View. An ExpandableListView is a scrollable View. `Nesting scrollable Views is **EVIL**`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assume that the child element of every group is `a list of size equal to 1`. So, other parts of the adapter should be as usual with the exception of `getChildView()` and `getChildrenCount()`. In addition you may use the same object type as group and child.

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //String url = mList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition);
        String url = mList.get(groupPosition).getUrl();

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fermata_adapter_body, null);
            mWebView = (WebView) rowView.findViewById(R.id....); 
            ...
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;//every group has 1 child
    }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mList.get(groupPosition);//or mList.get(groupPosition).getUrl();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mList.get(groupPosition);
    }
```

For better usability, you may need to use networking libraries like  [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)   to load the web content rather than simply saying `mWebView.loadUrl(url)`

Comment: Question 1: How to handle the tel and href occurred in this HTML in Fragment? I guess its not good practice to override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)...what is the best way to handle it?